# How to get a content generated in a particular url by using Jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, geturl

I have a requirement in which **i need to get the content generated in a particular url** (which is in JSON). I **need to assign this output to my json object after my jQuery ajax call**.I've tried this by using the following code, but not yeilding any result (always getting null within the success function parameter).

My Jquery ajax call code is as follows,

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://some url",
       data : {},
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (obj) {               
           alert(obj);
           var test = eval("(" + obj + ")");             
           alert(test);        

       },
       error: function () {
           alert("error");
       }
   })
```

Is there any error in my request? If this is not the right method please do suggest a method for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems here.  First, you won't be able to alert it.  Use

```
console.log(obj);
```

And then check it out in Firebug.

As for your request, you need to iterate through them (and you can exclude data altogether if it is empty)...

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://some url",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (data) {   
               $.each(data, function(idx, obj){    
                    console.log(obj);
               });              
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("error");
       }
   })
```

That should work if the URL is actually giving you valid json.

Comment: The firebug console too shows the object null as i got it earlier with alert(). My url is yielding a valid json.

Comment: Are you using console.log within the loop?  Can you post the code that creates the json output?

Comment: The problem was, i tried to sent the url request to a different server and this can't be done using jquery ajax.